# setHidesBackButton does not work

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

this one is driving me crazy.
From my root view controller I'm pushing another view controller to force the user to enter some credentials in order to login. Unless the credentials aren't correct the user shall not be able to switch back to the root view. To accomplish this I'm trying to hide the back button but for some reason this doesn't work.
Any suggestions?

```
- (void)presentLoginWebView
{
  UIViewController *webViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
  webViewController.title = NSLocalizedString(@"IB_LOG_IN_TITLE", nil);

  UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webViewController.view.frame];
  webViewController.view = webView;

  [self.navigationController pushViewController:webViewController animated:NO];

  [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:IB_GET_OAUTH_TOKEN_URL]]];
  webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
  webView.delegate = self; //delegate methods below

  if (deviceVersion > 6)
  {
    [self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer setEnabled:NO];
  }
  [self.navigationController.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];

  //The following line doesn't work either
  //self.presentedViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:[[UIView alloc] init]];
}
```

Comment: try `webViewController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working... This my friend could be the accepted answer.

Comment: Then I'll put this as answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try hiding back button of `webViewController`

```
webViewController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code will work. Try only `navigationItem` , not `navigationController.navigationItem`

```
webViewController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Comment: I tried this as well but unfortunately this doesn't work either.

Comment: Sorry, self was wrong there. webViewController.navigationItem will work as above. My mistake.